Есть ли решение проблемы четырех красок?
Есть ли решение проблемы четырех красок?
С коллегами на математическом эксперименте обсуждаем сейчас эту тему, что скажете?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Неужели вас с коллегами забанили в Википедии? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Summary_of_proof_ideas

Что за математический эксперимент?

Да, решение есть. Она была доказана (решена) в 1976 году.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem.

Хорошо бы ссылку какую-то приложить. И если можно краткое изложение сути сделать, то тоже приложить.

Благодарю за ответ! Спор вышел потому что доказывали теорему долго. Несколько раз публиковались, а потом опровергались доказательства. Да и на источниках везде своя точка зрения.
